# Making xinput change permenant

Tags: startup, mouse-wheel

I don't like the default functionality of the mouse's scroll wheel click doing a "paste".  I can change that by doing the follwing:

```
$ xinput set-button-map 12 1 0 3 4 5 6 7
```

This works fine, but if I reboot, I have to remember to do it again.

My question is how can I make this happen automatically if I need to reboot, etc?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: FWIW, there's now also a similar question and [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1293796/355456), which works with [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(protocol)#Adoption) (in 21.04 and later).

Answer (score 3):

You have to add that line in your `.xsessionrc` file. To do this, use the following command:

```
echo "xinput set-button-map 12 1 0 3 4 5 6 7" >> ~/.xsessionrc
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either run the command at every login or you can put it in the X.org configuration (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`) like this:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse"
    Driver         "evdev"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB-PS_2_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse"
    Option         "ButtonMapping" "12 1 0 3 4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

I don't know the identifiers and driver options of your device, but you get those with `xinput` and by sniffing around in `/dev/input`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use startx or init 3, the xessionrc is a good solution

```
echo "xinput..yourcommand" >> $HOME/.xsessionrc
```

If you use xfce on init 4/5 a good solution is to create a .destkop file which point to a script, in which you type the commands.

For example

```
vim  .config/autostart/xinput.desktop
    [Desktop Entry]
    Hidden=false
    Version=1.0
    Name=xinput
    Name[no]=xinput
    Name[pt_BR]=xinput
    Name[ru]=xinput
    Name[sl]=xinput
    Name[sv]=xinput
    Comment=xinput
    Comment[no]=xinput
    Icon=xinput
    Terminal=false
    Type=Application
    StartupNotify=false
    Categories=System;
    Exec=/home/you/scripts/xinput.sh
    RunHook=0
```

vim /home/you/scripts/xinput.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput..yourcommand
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x /home/you/scripts/xinput.sh
```

At the next login the command will run.