# How do I completely disable middle click (using wayland on kubuntu 23.10, plasma 5.27)

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, kde, wayland

My laptop's touchpad is a little sensitive and sometimes translates my attempts at left clicks as middle clicks.

I disabled 'middle click paste' in System Settings -> Workspace Behaviour but I still find annoying interactions in programs like:

- vscode (i believe this uses xwayland rather than wayland so this setting isn't being applied and it keeps middle click pasting)
- firefox, where middle click is leading to randomly closed windows, links being opened in a new tab when I don't want to

I want to just completely disable middle click inputs consistently everywhere. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `input-remapper-gtk` on Wayland: https://askubuntu.com/a/1487256/1004020